# Parameter error creating a query

Tags: java, sql

I'm getting the error

> java.sql.SQLExeption: Parameter index out of range (1>number of parameters, which is 0)

Here's my code:

```
private void salvaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      


    int codice = Integer.parseInt(cod.getText());
    String descrizione = des.getText();
    int quantita = Integer.parseInt(qua.getText());
    double prezzo = Integer.parseInt(pre.getText());


     try{   

        Connection conne = Connessione.conn();
        String query = "insert into prodotti(codice, descrizione, quantita', prezzo) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = conne.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setInt(1,codice);
        statement.setString(2,descrizione);
        statement.setInt(3,quantita);
        statement.setDouble(4,prezzo);
        statement.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exception: "+ e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Add stacktrace also.

Comment: The single quote after `quantita` looks suspect. Try removing it

Comment: The problem is that the single quote in `quantita'`. Remove it, check that everything works, and delete the question before someone adds this as an answer. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Yes thank you...i found out yesterday that quantita' written in that way caused errors in my sql query. Thanks for your time